# About GetAttestationAsync value with Windows10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10

The value obtained using the Get AttestationAsync, what kind of information include.
Server and whether to carry out the matching of this value,
 tell us about the authentication procedure using this valie.

windows-10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want you to tell me the following information I want to know.

1. Do the values obtained using the GetAttestationAsync, contain any information.
2. transmits the acquired information to the server, by comparing the time of authentication, either being enhanced to which security is.

And information of AttestationBuffer is, brute string to a unique ID for each model of the Authenticator.
- On the server side to compare this to.
- Using the Authenticator of different models to prevent a spoofing attack of.

What is consistent with the above idea.